# Interlaced array

Tags: code-golf, array

You are given an array `A` of length `N` and an array `B` of length `N-1`.

You need to output array where items alternates:

```
A[0], B[0], A[1], B[1], ..., B[N-2], A[N-1]
```

**Restrictions:**

```
N>0
```

Type of items is not specified, but code should work at least for unsigned integers.

**Sample input:**

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
B = [7,8,9]
```

**Sample output:**

```
[1,7,2,8,3,9,4]
```

**Edge case input:**

```
A = ['Hello, world']
B = []
```

**Edge case output:**

```
['Hello, world']
```

---

This question is a simplified version of [Zip uneven lists](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/244049/zip-uneven-lists).

Comment: Will the arrays always contain positive integers as in the example? Will they always be sorted? Will `N` always be at least 2? Please add test cases to cover those possibilities, if applicable

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/244049/92901)

Comment: The edge case does not satisfy the criteria in the question.  According to the specification, B should be one element shorter than A.  In your edge case, it is 2 elements shorter.

Comment: @Xcali no, array A has length 1.

Comment: Looking at the answers I am convinced this is a duplicate of the question Dingus has linked.  The differences here are trivial.

Comment: Ok. Sorry for that.

Comment: No need to apologize for asking a duplicate. It happens all the time that two people had the same idea or very similar ideas. Usually that's an indication it is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>36</s></sup> 34 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)*

```python
lambda a,b:sum(zip(a,b+a),())[:-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIVEnyaq4NFejKrNAA8jWTtTU0dDUjLbSNYz9X1CUmVeikaYRbaijYKSjYKyjYBKroxBtrqNgoaNgGaupyQVXoe6RmpOTr6NQnl@Uk6IOUgWU/g8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2), 1 byte

```
Y
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJZIiwiIiwiNyw4LDlcbjEsMiwzLDQiXQ==)

It's a built in. Takes B then A

Comment: Can you change the order of arrays, so that the bigger one comes first?

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

Expects `(A,B)` and returns a new array.

-2 bytes if the integers are guaranteed to be positive, in which case this is identical to [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/244073/58563) to [this closely related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/244049/58563).

```javascript
f=([v,...a],b)=>1/v?[v,...f(b,a)]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zVYjukxHT08vMVYnSdPWzlC/zB4ikKaRpJOoGWuV@D8ntUTBUcFWIdpQx0jHWMckVodLAQicQELmOhY6lrHWXFzJ@XnF@Tmpejn56RppGo46Tpqa1v8B)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Expects `(A)(B)`. Outputs by modifying `A`.

```javascript
a=>b=>b.map((v,i)=>a.splice(i-~i,0,v))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FchNCsMgEEDhvadwOQMT6R@0RQwk1whZWGvKFBulBpe5urWPt/rettjsvpy2bo1PXxdTrekfbfWxCaAQo@mtyimw88DdznSggliD3@QgjZyOdKIzXWYSsjX@6Uo3us9aiAUGhBG1cHHNMXgV4quRrj8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 40 bytes

```perl
sub{grep/./,map{$_,$_[1][$i++]}@{$_[0]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r5Jm@7@4NKk6vSi1QF9PXyc3saBaJV5HJT7aMDZaJVNbO7bWASgQbRBbW/vfujixUiEtv0hNJU0j2lDHSMdYxyRWJ9pUx0zHPFbzv6GCkYKxggmXqYKZgvm//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 2 bytes

```
żẎ
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCLFvOG6jiIsIiIsIiIsWyIxLDIsMyw0IiwiNyw4LDkiXV0=)

I don't think there's a built-in directly for this...? Interleaving returns a 2D list and then we flatten it by one level (so even if either list is more than depth 1, this should be correct).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 19 bytes

```hs
(a:x)!b=a:b!x
a!_=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyPRqkJTMck20SpJsYIrUTHeNvF/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCtKGOgpGOgrGOgkmsgqJCtKmOgpmOgnnsfwA)

-4 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard

Defines an infix function `!` (thanks to Wheat Wizard for this optimization) that returns `[a[0], ...]` (swapping arguments, so next we get `[b[0], ...]` which is followed by `[a[1], ...]`, etc.) or if `b` is empty, just `a`.

---

#### [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 28 bytes

```ml
fun f[]a=a|f(a::x)b=a::f b x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxNCsIwGAX3OcUjqwY@hfoLLTlA1y5DhASJFNK0tBEq9O4xCgrF1SzezJs6v@l87ENK7hHglDbSLK4wVTULKzMcLObPeGunwZsn3qPSAhJNiNvYX@LYhjsMA5aVZP8dXMEJPOMr2lWmdE44ZzUbchBR/P4cVEnYEfaEg4Y6Ek6EsxaiTi8)

---

#### [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 31 bytes

```ml
f=(a,b)=>b?a[to1]+f(b,a[1to]):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CsAwCADQqzga6pJ@oZD2IOJghkCXGIL3t@@NaW49ohVUqqk89VV2y7I0rKSc3STdGmN@3bEhZ4KVYCPYhYAPgpPgkpTiBw)

Comment: Some slight optimizations: You can make `f` an infix function, and you can save a byte by swapping your cases: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyPRqkJTUSPJqlLTNtEqyapCsZIrUTHeNvF/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCtKGOgpGOgrGOgkmsgqJCtKmOgpmOgnnsfwA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @WheatWizard Oh that's neat, I did not realize you can just define infix functions like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 28 bytes

```
O#$`\d+(?<=((,)|.)+)
$#2
¶
,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P/fX1klISZFW8PexlZDQ0ezRk9TW5NLRdmI69A2Lp3//w11jHSMdUy4zHUsdCwB) Takes two comma separated lists of unsigned integers as input. Explanation:

```
O#$`\d+(?<=((,)|.)+)
$#2
```

Sort each value by the number of preceding commas in its line.

```
¶
,
```

Join the two lists together.

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＵＭθ⮌ιＷ§θⅉ⟦Ｉ⊟ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/983scA5Pzc3MS9Fo1BHISi1LLWoOFUjU1PTmqs8IzMnVUHDscQzLyW1AiQdqaGpqakQUJSZV6IR7ZxYXKIRkF8AUhyraf3/f3R0tKGOkY6xjkmsTrS5joWOZWxs7H/dshwA) Takes input as a pair of lists. Explanation: Same as my answer to the duplicate challenge.

```
ＵＭθ⮌ι
```

Reverse each of the two lists.

```
Ｗ§θⅉ
```

Cyclically index the lists according to the number of values already output and repeat until that list is empty.

```
⟦Ｉ⊟ι
```

Output the "next" value from that list on its own line.